# Get a reaction resultant by automatically summing nodal reactions

Tags: abaqus

In Abaqus, I want to compute the force resulting from a pressure I apply on a surface. This force is the sum of the nodal reactions of all nodes belonging to the surface.

Using `history output`, the only thing I can do is exporting the individual nodal reactions, which becomes awkward to handle when there is a lot of nodes.

So, is there a simple way, in the `CAE` interface or in the `.inp` input file to do this in a straightforward way?

Comment: Do you have an `RF fieldOutput`?

Comment: Yes I can request for this, it is not a problem (and it is a default setup of Abaqus)

Comment: If you get the `RF` on the nodes, then you have your reaction force.

Comment: I want to sum them over a nset. My question is : how to get a resultant (the sum of all nodal reaction), from a field of nodal reaction ? I don't want the `fieldOutput`, I want a single vector (in 2D or 3D).

Comment: If you're looking for the Abaqus command to do it, it's `session.odbs[path_to_odb_file_as_string].steps[step_name_as_string].frames[frame_number_as_int].fieldOutputs['RF'].values[n].data` where `n` is the nth node. The node label can be accessed by `values[n].nodeLabel`.

Answer (score 3):

In Abaqus/Standard, you may print nodal and/or element output to the data file (.dat) using the `*node print` input file keyword. In Standard or Explicit, you may print to the results file (.fil/.sel) using `*node file`. The keyword can be used for an individual node or for an entire node set. You can control whether the values are totaled, whether the output is in a local or global coordinate system, whether a summary is also printed, and the frequency the output is written to file.

The options and defaults are slightly different between `*node print` and `*node file` - for example, the `summary` and `totals` args are only available for `node print`. See the docs for more detail.

These keywords have to be placed within a Step definition. Assuming you have already defined the `nset` of interest, you can do something like:

```
*node print, nset=my_nset, totals=yes, global=yes
RF,
*node file, nset=my_nset, global=yes, frequency=999
RF,
```